# How to make an exact copy of image in java?

Tags: java, image

After loading the image, I want to create an exact copy of the image whereby the quality and scale can remain the same. With my current code, the quality was reduced.

```
public class Image {
    private static final String path = "C:/Users.../src/7horses.jpg";
    private static final File file = new File(path);

    static BufferedImage deepCopy(BufferedImage bi) throws IOException {
        String saveAs = "copy.jpg";
        ColorModel cm = bi.getColorModel();
        boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
        WritableRaster raster = bi.copyData(null);
        BufferedImage cImg = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
        File saveImage = new File("C:/Users.../src", saveAs);
        ImageIO.write(cImg, "jpg", saveImage);
        return cImg;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage cp, img;
        img = ImageIO.read(file); 
        cp = deepCopy(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: You understand that you're copying lossy data, right? How can this ever be "exactly copied" without loss of quality? If this is your goal, then use non-lossy compressed image data type.

Comment: was it because its BufferedImage?

Comment: if you want exact copy of your image, why just not simple copy file?

Comment: It has nothing to do with BufferedImage and all to do with JPG.

Comment: What @user902383 said!

Comment: So its almost impossible to create an exact copy due to JPEG's lossy compression?

Comment: Lossy JPEG will lose information. You would have to use a lossless JPEG compression to retain the original image. It all comes at a cost though.

Comment: To make an exact copy of the image you will need to do a byte by byte copy from one file to the other without making any changes or modifications to the bytes as you copy them.  As soon as you make a change to a byte, you are going to introduce artifacts that will result in differences between input and output.  The problem you will run into is that jpeg is not an exact pixel by pixel image of the scene.  The pixel by pixel image of the scene is run through a compression algorithm which removes details.  More compression, less detail.  Byte by byte copy will replicate the same compression.

Comment: The fact that the source file is jpg does not keep one from copying that image without introducing any further loss.  If you really only want to copy the image file to another file just to a file copy and don't go into the image processing world in your Java code.

Comment: @RichardChambers That's not *entirely* true. You have to avoid decoding and re-encoding the image data, and copy the file byte by byte does that. You could also read through the JFIF segments, changing some of them (such as adding or removing a thumbnail or changing, adding, or deleting a comment), as long as when it came to the image data you passed it through unchanged without decoding and encoding it.

Comment: @DavidConrad, are you telling me that if I just open a new empty file then open an existing jpeg file and then copy bytes from the jpeg file to the new empty file until I reach the end of the jpeg file it will not work?  This is the basis for every raw copy utility every born since the days when IBM 360 ruled the earth.

Comment: @RichardChambers No, I'm telling you that is not the *only* thing that will work.

Answer (score 6):

try just to copy your image file, use this code :

```
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/img/src"));
            os = new FileOutputStream(new File("path/to/img/dest"));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
```

if you are using **Java 8** then you can just call `Files.copy` method, check it in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-)

Comment: Even before Java 8 you could use Apache Commons IOUtils to simplify copying from one stream to the other. Also, 1024 is a pretty small buffer size. I would recommend at least 8192.

Answer (score 0):

Go from using:

```
ImageIO.write(cImg, "jpg", saveImage);
```

To the following:  (Don't have my dev environment here to test this but think I have this close for you.)

```
Iterator iterator = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");
ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter)iterator.next();
ImageWriteParam imageWriteParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();


imageWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
imageWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(1); //0 is max Compression  1 is max quality

FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(saveImage);
writer.setOutput(output);

IIOImage image = new IIOImage(cImg, null, null);
writer.write(null, image, iwp);
writer.dispose();
output.close();
```

Comment: This is still re-encoding the image data which, with a lossy format like JPEG, will inevitably cause a loss of fidelity in the image.

Comment: In my experience setting the CompressionQuality to 1 does not result in a loss of quality it retains the quality of the original image. In essence your saying save my image as a JPG but do not compress it.

Comment: I am not sure if it loosing the fidelity of the original image, doesn't appear to the naked eye, but this is increasing my file size from 5M to 7.7M