# NoSuchFileException using File.copy

Tags: java

I got the following error when trying to copy an image file from one folder to another.

Error message :

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\William\Pictures\D8McXhNVUAE7VFh.jpg -> \resources\6.jpg
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
    at data.DAO.addEmployee(DAO.java:130)
    at GUI.NewUser$3.actionPerformed(NewUser.java:184)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
```

My code as:

```
String sourceFile = "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Pictures\D8McXhNVUAE7VFh.jpg"
String destinationFilePath = "\\resources\\" + generatedID + ".jpg" ;
File sourceFile = new File(imageSourcePath);
File destinationFile = new File(destinationFilePath);
Path sourcePath = sourceFile.toPath();
Path destinationPath = destinationFile.toPath();
try {
          Files.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);
} catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

What could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Either the source file doesn't exist or the destination file path doesn't exist. I don't program on Windows, but that path looks fishy to me.

Answer (score 3):

You have used same variable name in `String sourceFile` and `File sourceFile`. Please **rename** one of them.

for an example use this

```
ex -: String sourceFile
      File file
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double backslashes in your path string, e.g. `C:\\Users\\xxxxxx\\Pictures\\D8McXhNVUAE7VFh.jpg`

Comment: That would cause a compilation error. They would not be able to run their program. It's pretty safe to assume that what they have there is just an example input.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using Files.copy for images you should copy by stream .

```
URI u = URI.create("file:///C:\Users\xxxxxx\Pictures\D8McXhNVUAE7VFh.jpg");
 try (InputStream in = u.toURL().openStream()) {
     Files.copy(in, path);
 }
```

Adding If you need to copy by Inout stream :

[How to make an exact copy of image in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807725/how-to-make-an-exact-copy-of-image-in-java)